# Xlib Sending Characters to Text Editor

Tags: c, xlib

I am testing some features of X, and using Xlib to manipulate X.

The problem is I cannot send some basic characters to text editor. My purpose is sending those characters via Xlib's `XSendEvent()` function to the other window, which I know its ID exactly.

The code is:

```
int read_window() {

    static Display *dpy;
    static int scr;
    static Window root;
    static Window win;

    XEvent ev;

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(getenv("DISPLAY"));

    if (dpy == NULL) {
        errx(1, "Cannot open display.");
    }

    scr = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    root = RootWindow(dpy, scr);

    win = 0x6600006; // Window ID of Kate text editor.

    XSelectInput(dpy, win, KeyPress);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {

        static XEvent evts;
        evts.xkey.type = KeyPress;
        evts.xkey.display = dpy;
        evts.xkey.keycode = 'A' + i;
        evts.xkey.same_screen = True;
        evts.xkey.send_event = 1;
        evts.xkey.state = 0;

        XSendEvent(dpy, win, False, KeyPress, &evts);

        XFlush(dpy);

        i++;
    }

    XCloseDisplay(dpy);

    return 0;
}
```

This code does not change anything on Kate text editor.

How to send key events to a text editor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for hours, I encountered with [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20070712224859/http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html) little program and problem is solved.

The new code is:

```
int read_window() {

    static Display *dpy;
    static int scr;
    static Window root;
    static Window win;

    XEvent ev;

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(getenv("DISPLAY"));

    if (dpy == NULL) {
        errx(1, "Cannot open display.");
    }

    scr = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    root = RootWindow(dpy, scr);

    win = 0x6600006;

    //XConfigureWindow(dpy, win, CWHeight | CWWidth | CWBorderWidth | CWX | CWY, &kate);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {

        static XEvent evts;
        evts.xkey.display = dpy;
        evts.xkey.window = win;
        evts.xkey.root = root;
        evts.xkey.time = CurrentTime;
        evts.xkey.x = 20;
        evts.xkey.y = 20;
        evts.xkey.x_root = 0;
        evts.xkey.y_root = 0;
        evts.xkey.same_screen = True;
        evts.xkey.keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(dpy, XK_B);
        evts.xkey.state = 0;
        evts.xkey.type = KeyPress;

        XSendEvent(dpy, win, True, KeyPressMask, &evts);

        //sleep(1);
        //XWarpPointer(dpy, None, RootWindow(dpy,scr), 0, 0, 1080, 1920, 200*i, 200*i);
        XFlush(dpy);

        i++;
    }

    XCloseDisplay(dpy);

    return 0;
}
```